# Normalize m:s to h:m:s

Tags: mysql, normalization

How can I normalize this column to all fields be in "%T" format? Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)

Query SQL: SELECT duration FROM time_tbl;

```
Results exemples:
2:43:30
52:53
0:01
1:58:21
28:56
NULL
02:05:35
```

Comment: And `52:53` has to be what? `00:52:53`?

Comment: Please add the desired result.

Comment: Exactly, when I try "TIME_FORMAT(duration, '%H:%i:%s')" doesn't works. Because the supposed minutes changes to hour

Comment: I need for example:
`   02:43:30
    00:52:53
    00:00:01
    01:58:21
    00:28:56
    00:00:00
    02:05:35`

Comment: What is the data type of `duration`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to fill in the missing part:

```
SELECT LPAD(duration, 8, '00:00:00')
  FROM time_tbl;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3417e/5/0)

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly!